# sel4 Verify the environment setup

Tags: isabelle, sel4

Now I am setting up sel4 verification environment, but I see the blogger said "link isabelle path to verification directory", I would like to ask what it means？

Do you want to download isabelle to the verification directory？

Answer (score 1):

To set up a verification environment for seL4, you should follow these steps:

- install the Google repo tool and download the seL4 verification manifest as described here: https://github.com/seL4/verification-manifest/blob/master/README.md
- install the dependencies for seL4 verification as described here: https://github.com/seL4/l4v/blob/master/docs/setup.md
- run proofs as described here: https://github.com/seL4/l4v/#running-the-proofs

Comment: The download for the Google repo tool seems to have changed and is now here: https://source.android.com/docs/setup/download